# Loading class as a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a class

```
public class Orders
{
    public Orders() {}

    private string _idOrder;
    private string _totalPrice;

    public string idOrder 
    { 
        get{ return _idOrder;}
        set { _idOrder = value;}  
    }

    public string totalPrice
    {
        get { return _totalPrice; }
        set { _totalPrice = value; }  
    }
}
```

I am loading the list from database like this

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    Orders.idOrder = dr["IdOrder"].ToString();
    Orders.totalPrice= dr["totalPrice"].ToString();
}
```

It's is showing me only last record. How can I load all the orders and retrieve them back by foreach loop?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I am not aware how to create list in such type of scenerio. I am a beginner :-)

Comment: yield return just collect your values and return it as a list.After yield return control will not exit from function

Comment: If you don't need Orders List for more than one time you better to use @Grook way. And If you need them u better to use @"Daniel Hilgarth" way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a list :-)

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Order order = new Order();
    order.idOrder = dr["IdOrder"].ToString();
    order.totalPrice= dr["totalPrice"].ToString();
    orders.Add(order);
}
```

As you see, I renamed your class from `Orders` to `Order`, because that's what it really represents: *One* order. To have more orders, you need to put those single orders into a list.

Comment: With the exception that your's won't compile ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
IEnumberable<Order> FetchOrders()
{
    while(dr.Read())
        yield return new Order {
          idOrder=dr["IdOrder"].ToString(), 
          totalPrice=dr["totalPrice"].ToString()
        });
}
```

Comment: It think your answer is near what he or she wants.+1

Comment: @Grook I am little confused with the statement  yield return

Comment: @Grook: I think your answer is too complicated for a beginner. (no vote).

Comment: @Grook: I never would have thought of exposing it as an IEnumerable... that's actually pretty neat (especially memory-wise)... presuming that ONE forward-only iteration is all that's required in the ACTUAL processing... and if a List **is** actually required then it's childsplay to create one from an enumeration. I like it. Thanx for the fish. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: @Chris: You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)
@DanielHilgarth: For beginner it is just usefull and comfortable way to solve this problem. And, maybe, he(she) will read about it and obtain this technique.

Comment: @Grook: He will not use it, because he doesn't understand it :) I think it's better to first learn the basics and then proceed. Otherwise, he will have a piece of code in his program he doesn't understand. However, hopefully, he remembers it in the future, that there was "something", and will look it up, when he has the necessary basic knowledge. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth i tryed to say same thing but my english is not so good to say is as good as you did :)

Answer (score 2):

It's only showing you the one item, because you're only changing properties on the one item, not instantiating a new one:

```
var results = new List<Order>();

while (reader.Read())
{
  var order = new Order
  {
    Id = (int)reader["IdOrder"],
    TotalPrice = (decimal)reader["totalPrice"]
  };

  results.Add(order);
}
```

Comment: Alas, but idOrder and TotalPrice are strings

Comment: Very true, but I think he also needs to address type casing, member naming conventions and proper type use too ;-)

Comment: @Rakshit, I think Matt has a couple of good points here. Storing an integer Id (if it is an integer value?) in a string field is just plain ole inefficient.... AND Storing a Price (any monetary amount) in a string field is just plain WRONG! One thing computer do a LOT of is add-up money... so shouldn't Price be stored as a number? And `decimal` is a good choice for money values, because calculations on decimals produce accurate (or alteast predictable) results.

Answer (score 2):

That `Orders` class represents a **single** order! If what you need is a list of orders then I suggest you rename that class to Order, and then create a `List<Order>` (a list of order-objects) and populate that from your query results.

Also (forgive me for being pernickety) "idOrder" is not a good field name. The standard approaches are "orderId" or just plain old "Id" (ID, or even id). Likewise I would expect the price-of-ONE-order to be called just "amount", or even "price"... not "totalPrice"... it'll be too confusing when you come to total-up the totalPrices... get my drift?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I'm Waaaaay Too Slow! Must be gettin old! ;-)

Comment: +1 for description. I really need to understand as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that will compile. Orders.idOrder is not a static property, it's an instance property.

Comment: It is compiling correctly and I am getting the output too. Am I doing anything incorrect? Advice me so that I can correct the logic

Comment: How can you set Orders.idOrder when idOrder (and its backing member) is not declared static?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you want to use something like this:

```
List<Order> = new List<Order>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Order newOrder = new Order();
    newOrder.idOrder = dr["IdOrder"].ToString();
    newOrder.totalPrice= dr["totalPrice"].ToString();
    orderList.Add(newOrder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice this that **I just discuss more for @Grook Answer**. I Think it is so near to what to want.

```
IEnumberable<Order> FetchOrders()
{
    while(dr.Read())
        yield return new Order {
          idOrder=dr["IdOrder"].ToString(), 
          totalPrice=dr["totalPrice"].ToString()
        });
}
```

Then You can easily use foreach loop

```
Foreach(Order order in GetOrders())
{
 doSomething(order);
}
```

**Is it clear?**